# Why is the sizeof union not 8 bytes but 4 bytes even if I am using pointer in my union?

Tags: c, unions

```
union one
{
    int *ui;
    int u;
        
} yoo;

void main() 
{
    printf("%d\m", sizeof(yoo))
}
```

Why is the sizeof union not 8 bytes but 4 bytes even if I am using pointer in my union?

I am using a 64 bit machine.

Comment: For one thing you have *undefined behavior* in your code: The `%d` format expects an `int` argument, while the result of `sizeof` is a value of the type `size_t`. To print a `size_t` value you must use `%zu`.

Comment: With that said, even if you're on a 64-bit system, perhaps your code is built as a 32-bit application? How do you build? What compiler are you using? What version of it? What options and flags do you pass when building?

Comment: Confirm by directly printing `sizeof(int *)`

Comment: please show the command used to compile this code

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when i run gcc -dumpmachine  it gives the output as 'i686-w64-mingw32'. does this represent that i am using a 32 bit version. Also the output of gcc --version is 'gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)' .

Comment: Yes that's a 32-bit compiler which will generate 32-bit executables. The compiler itself is built for 64-bit Windows (the `w64` part) but its default target is the 32-bit `i686` systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have compiled it as 32-bit executable.